# Selenium Webdriver: Drag and Drop not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, action

**Scenario:**

1. Drag hamburger menu
2. Drop it at the destination which is below Workflow Canvas

Below is HTML code for source and destination:

**Source HTML:**
https://monosnap.com/file/VWHq7ve1tMtqQbX1S34JA3ttEQT5Dc

**Destination HTML:**
https://monosnap.com/file/mhYkXwrz4EzI2ns98skP4ffW9IlD47

Searched for a solution and below are few ways which I tried but didn't work:

```java
WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='fa fa-bars handle']"));
WebElement desc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='dragArea list-group']"));

Actions act = new Actions(driver);

Way #1: act.dragAndDrop(source, desc).build().perform();
Way #2: act.dragAndDrop(source, desc).click().build().perform();
Way #3: act.clickAndHold(source).moveToElement(desc).release(source).build().perform();
Way #4: org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action dragAndDrop = act.clickAndHold(source).moveToElement(desc1).release(desc1).build();
dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Please let me know how can I automate this scenario.

Comment: Update the question with text based relevant HTML

Comment: Please can you also add the full exception stack trace in the description?